# how to manage multiple checkboxes in ember?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm still trying to figure out how ember works and I want to have more info on managing multiple checkboxes in ember..
here's what I tried to do: http://jsbin.com/datojebu/2/edit
as you can see all checkboxes get selected and the checked function doesn't get called
what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay further to your additional questions, I've basically finished your app for you:

http://jsbin.com/datojebu/11/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '/api',
    namespace: 'fr'
});

/* router */
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('animes');
});
App.AnimesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('anime');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super();
    this.store.find('genre').then(function(genres) {
      controller.set('genres', genres);
    });
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});

/* models */
var model = DS.Model,
    attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany;

App.Genre = model.extend({
    animes: hasMany('anime', {async: true}),
    nom: attr('string')
});
App.Anime = model.extend({
    nom: attr('string'),
    parution: attr('number'),
    synopsis: attr('string'),
    likes: attr('number'),
    auteur: attr('string'),

    genres: hasMany('genre', {async: true})
});
/* controllers */
App.AnimesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  genres: Em.A([]),
  selectedGenreIds: Em.A([]), // a set of ids
  selectedGenres: function() {
    var genres = this.get('genres'),
        selectedGenreIds = this.get('selectedGenreIds');
    return genres.filter(function(genre) {
      return selectedGenreIds.contains(genre.get('id'));
    });
  }.property('selectedGenreIds.@each', 'genres.@each'),
  selectedAnimes: function() {
    var allAnimes = this.get('model'),
        selectedGenres = this.get('selectedGenres'),
        filteredAnimes;
    // for an anime to be shown, it has to have at
    // least one of its genres selected
    filteredAnimes = allAnimes.filter(function(anime) {
      return anime.get('genres').any(function(animeGenre) {
        return selectedGenres.contains(animeGenre);
      });
    });
    return filteredAnimes;
  }.property('model.@each', 'selectedGenres.@each', 'genres.@each')
});
App.GenreController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['animes'],
  isChecked: function(key, value) {
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
      // setter
      var selectedGenreIds = this.get('controllers.animes.selectedGenreIds'),
          thisId = this.get('id');
      if(!selectedGenreIds.contains(thisId) && value) {
        selectedGenreIds.addObject(thisId);
      } else {
        selectedGenreIds.removeObject(thisId);
      }
    }
    // always return the value for the getter and the setter
      return value;
  }.property('controllers.animes.selectedGenreIds')
});

/* mockjax */
var animes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'Blah',
        parution: 2014,
        genres: [1, 3],
        synopsis: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, eveniet, ab pariatur omnis dolor sunt alias atque voluptate neque reiciendis maiores impedit quibusdam perferendis optio ratione expedita adipisci et. Cupiditate!',
        likes: 206,
        auteur: 'Moi :p'
    }
],
genres = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'action',
        animes: []
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nom: 'magie',
        animes: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nom: 'amour et amitier',
        animes: []
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        nom: 'aventures',
        animes: [1]
    }
];
$.mockjax({
  url: '/api/fr/animes',
  responseTime: 750,
  responseText: {
    'animes': animes
  }
});
$.mockjax({
  url: '/api/fr/genres',
  responseTime: 750,
  responseText: {
    'genres': genres
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry.. :/ I didn't mean to let you write my app.. but I really find Ember confusing.. so thanks a lot! this is really helpful

Comment: Haha I didn't mean to come off snarky! :) Yeah, it *is* confusing. Don't worry. I find it confusing and difficult, too. I'm actually in the process of making a video series that should go from absolute beginner... so that might be helpful. Maybe I should launch a kickstarter for it :)

Comment: Do you understand everything I did? It's good to make sure you understood the logic of it. I tried to put comments in to help, but it might be a bit confusing still.

Comment: yes, the code is really clear.. but I don't understand the meaning of `needs: ['animes']`.. and I wasn't aware of the possibility to access another controller with `this.get('controllers.animes.selectedGenreIds')` for example :)   and be sure to let me know when you're done with your series ^^

Comment: Actually needs['something'] is how you specify what you **can** access with this.get('controllers.something'); (If that makes sense).

So... you can say needs: ['animes'] which "mounts" the controller into the controllers attribute which you can then access with this.get('controllers.animes');

Comment: Check out http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Answer (score 2):

Check this now. http://jsbin.com/datojebu/3/edit

```
  {{#each genre in genres}}
       {{input type="checkbox" name=genre.id checked=genre.isChecked}} {{genre.nom}}
  {{/each}}
```

you have to add genre.isChecked else same isChecked will be binded to all checkboxes.

BTW if you want to have controller for each item, you can add ItemController in the array controller. Here is another example.

```
/* controllers */
App.AnimesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'anime'
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still can't understand the way to know which one is checked so that it can be used in filtering for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as CodeJack said...

Once you've done that, you use bindings to "know" which one is checked. That is to say you don't need to **know** it yourself, you just need to bind the correct values to the right spot.

Anyway, this jsbin should alleviate your issues... notice the console gets set with the value and triggered at the correct tiems/places.

http://jsbin.com/datojebu/6/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '/api',
    namespace: 'fr'
});

/* router */
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('animes');
});
App.AnimesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('anime');
    },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.store.find('genre').then(function(genres){
            controller.set('genres', genres);
        });
    }
});

/* models */
var model = DS.Model,
    attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany;

App.Genre = model.extend({
    animes: hasMany('anime', {async: true}),
    nom: attr('string')
});
App.Anime = model.extend({
    nom: attr('string'),
    parution: attr('number'),
    synopsis: attr('string'),
    likes: attr('number'),
    auteur: attr('string'),

    genres: hasMany('genre', {async: true})
});
/* controllers */
App.GenreController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  isChecked: function(key, value) {
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
      // setter
      console.log('huzzah' + this.get('id') + ' val: ' + value);      
    }
    // always return the value for the getter and the setter
    return this.get('model.isChecked');
  }.property(),
  actions: {
  click: function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }    
  }
});

/* mockjax */
var animes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'Blah',
        parution: 2014,
        genres: [1, 3],
        synopsis: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, eveniet, ab pariatur omnis dolor sunt alias atque voluptate neque reiciendis maiores impedit quibusdam perferendis optio ratione expedita adipisci et. Cupiditate!',
        likes: 206,
        auteur: 'Moi :p'
    }
],
genres = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nom: 'action',
        animes: []
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nom: 'magie',
        animes: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nom: 'amour et amitier',
        animes: []
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        nom: 'aventures',
        animes: [1]
    }
];
$.mockjax({
  url: '/api/fr/animes',
  responseTime: 750,
  responseText: {
    'animes': animes
  }
});
$.mockjax({
  url: '/api/fr/genres',
  responseTime: 750,
  responseText: {
    'genres': genres
  }
});
```

Comment: but at the end you return `this.get('model.isChecked')`.. which is `undefined`.. why?

Comment: and also now that you're using another controller for the checkboxes.. how can I observe them in the App.AnimesController..

Comment: It's not a controller for the checkboxes, it's a controller for the genres - as an itemController on each of the genres. The reason you need that is that you don't have a property on the actual genres themselves (which is probably correct). This entirely depends on what you want to do.

You seem to want to filter based on the checked or not checked state of these things. I suggest you use the isChecked function I've given you to drive the change in the filter code... (ie use it to manage some state on the controller that wraps the filtered items).

Comment: I was answering your specific questions... but if what you'd actually asked was how to go about creating a list of checkboxes that drive a filtered set of objects, well that's a different question!

If you want to, feel free to ask another question, but I think I've more than answered your first question here.

The question you **probably** wanted to ask is actually how can you use checkboxes to manage data-backed associations in ember. I would go about that in a fairly different way than what you've done, so it's a quesiton at a higher level of architecture.

Comment: Okay now I understand what you're actually asking and trying to do, I'll have a bit more of a think about it and see what I can do.

Comment: Okay I worked on this for a while. I've pretty much finished it for you, according to what I think you wanted to do.

Comment: @GregH I was simply following form. If you can get the OP to post his question with real code, I'll respond with real code. (I'm also a moderator, so I understand the criticism, but it's not exactly a minimum reproducible error, so maybe that should be worked on first rather than criticise the answerers).

Comment: @JulianLeviston you make a good point- i apologize for the review and will get it corrected. Thanks for calling this out

Comment: @GregH it's fine. I updated so that the code is inserted as well. :)